# Adding quotations at beginning and end of a line using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I know `sed 's/^/"/g'` works for the beginning of a line, and `sed 's/$/"/g'` works for the end, but why doesn't `sed 's/[^$]/"/g'` work for both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[^$]` means "any character except the dollar sign". So saying `sed 's/[^$]/"/g'` you are replacing all characters with `"`, except `$` ([credits to Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460096/adding-quotations-at-beginning-and-end-of-a-line-using-sed/30460194?noredirect=1#comment49005616_30460194)):

```
$ echo 'he^llo$you' | sed 's/[^$]/"/g'
""""""$"""
```

To say: match either `^` or `$`, you need to use the `( | )` expression:

```
sed 's/\(^\|$\)/"/g' file
```

or, if you have `-r` in your `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(^|$)/"/g' file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
bye
$ sed -r 's/(^|$)/"/g' a
"hello"
"bye"
```

Comment: `^` does not mean a literal `^` in the bracket expression `[^$]`, it means negation and because of that `$` does not mean a literal `$` in that specific case. The bracket expression `[^$]` means "any character except a dollar sign". Also, `^` and `$` as RE metachars mean beginning/end of string, not beginning/end of line - they just get misinterpreted as related to lines because sed and grep are line-oriented and so beg/end of string and beg/end of line in sed/grep usually are the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

```
sed 's/.*/"&"/' YourFile
```

Will do the same using full line as pattern replacement `&`.

In this case `g` is not needed because you only have 1 occurrence of the whole line per line (default behaviour of `sed` reading line by line)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' filename.txt
"tag1"
"tag2"
```

This serves your purpose also you can change the double quotes(") with required any other pattern also, like:

```
sed -e 's/^/<<</' -e 's/$/>>>' data.txt
<<<tag1>>>
<<tag2>>>
```